# IOS softkeyboard always comes up for a second

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I've got a CANVAS webapp that uses a small virtual on screen keyboard to enter numbers into a number field. Recently something changed where the virtual keyboard on IOS is no longer suppressed when clicking a number.

I've set the 'readonly' attribute, and I call blur on the textfield. but the keyboard always pops up for short second and leaves, before its even populated with keys.

Is there anyway to keep the IOS keyboard from showing up at all?

I've tried document.activeElement.blur(); to hide the keyboard and I've tried hiddenTextarea.setAttribute("readonly","readonly");    to forbid the keyboard and nothing works.